# ESLint: 'globalThis' is not defined

Tags: javascript, jsdom

There are similar questions with this same error message, but every one I found is a runtime error. For me, `globalThis` *does* exist at runtime, but ESLint reports that it does not. How do I tell ESLint that `globalThis` exists?

**Note**: I created this to answer it myself. I thought it should be documented outside of an obscure github issue.

Answer (score 3):

[@mdjermanovic documented the fix here](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/15199#issuecomment-948724014):

> `globalThis` is already supported. Since it's an ES2020 feature,
> you'll need to enable `es2020` (or higher)
> [environment](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-environments)
> in your configuration.
>
> ```json
> {
>     "env": {
>         "es2020": true
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Here's [online demo](https://eslint.org/demo#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiZ2xvYmFsVGhpcy5mb28gPSBcImZvb1wiOyIsIm9wdGlvbnMiOnsicGFyc2VyT3B0aW9ucyI6eyJlY21hVmVyc2lvbiI6MTMsInNvdXJjZVR5cGUiOiJzY3JpcHQiLCJlY21hRmVhdHVyZXMiOnt9fSwicnVsZXMiOnsibm8tdW5kZWYiOjJ9LCJlbnYiOnsiZXMyMDIxIjpmYWxzZSwiZXMyMDIwIjp0cnVlfX19) with `es2020` and `no-undef` enabled.
>
> *Originally posted by @mdjermanovic in https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/15199#issuecomment-948724014*

---

Note that [you can find older answers](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/11553#issuecomment-476570950) that suggest adding `globalThis` as an eslint "global" config, but the above solution is a more modern approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can also tell **ESLint** that `globalThis` exists.

Specify it in the ESLint configuration file by adding `globalThis` to the `globals` section.

```
{
   "globals": {
       "globalThis": "readonly"
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I noted that at the bottom of my answer, but I think this is "the old way" to do it.